# Low quality output

Tags: modeling, rendering, animation, mesh, uv

[environment.blend](https://drive.google.com/file/d/14E9-b-n1Yth8viizj4H3fAhnhA0AGtKw/view?usp=sharing)
[environment.blend1](https://drive.google.com/file/d/10Bhpr4Ol_VbyarnWnfCG3r0shkCV_nbC/view?usp=sharing)   [image][image]I've been using blender for a month or so , but now I've noticed that all the animation renders , i make , simple or complex , they all have low quality.I was following ducky3ds  environment tutorial , but all my animations were low quality.[image]

please help me increase the quality of this render coz i didn't expect this.
for , info the render is in eevee , blender 2.3.

[image]

Comment: Hello, what are your render settings? Are you using cycles, eevee, or internal(2.7x) render?  What is it specifically that you consider low quality? Please be specific and detailed in your question, and add more information in the form of an [edit to your question.](https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/183105/edit)  Thanks!

Comment: broo , pls dont get offended , im a beginer only not much experience , this is in eevee. blender 2.83 , you see those lines in the backgroung(dunno , what to call them)

Comment: Bro ,all this is to complex , just tell me how can i solve the problem and make , my render better , first tell , is the render bad according to you , if yes then how would you make it better , ive uploaded some more pics

Answer (score 0):

Its extremely hard to judge based on just images. A blend file would be helpful. Based on the images it seems the samples are low. Also you are exporting a video so could be encoding. Could be lighting setup as well.

Comment: ok bro , i have added the blend files for u in the edit , so now try to solve my probleimo

Comment: I cant access the files. I don't use Google drive much so Idk how to gain access to it

Comment: then how would i send you the blend files??